# Why am I getting this definition reference error?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I am using `TaskBar` methods defined within the namespace `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar`.  Specifically, I'll focus on `SetProgressState` for this question.

Here is the meta-definition I get when I ask for the definition of `SetProgressState`:

```
namespace Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar
{
    public class TaskbarManager
    {
        public void SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState state);
        public void SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState state, IntPtr windowHandle);
        public void SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState state, System.Windows.Window window);
    }
}
```

Obviously, I have omitted most of that class's definition just to highlight the one method's overloads.

To this point, I have been using the single-parameter overload and have had no issues.  However, today I attempted to use the two-parameter overload that accepts an `IntPtr` as its second parameter.

When I did that, I started getting this error during build:

> The type 'System.Windows.Window' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

So my question is why I did not get an error for using the single-parameter overload, but I *do* get an error for referencing one of the others (and for the *wrong one*)?

Edit (for addition sub-question):

I also tried the following, which made no difference:

```
SetProgressState(myState, (IntPtr) myWindowHandle);
```

I thought that by casting explicitly, I would avoid the compiler confusion in realizing the appropriate overload, but that was not the case.

Comment: Just wait for Eric Lippert to drop by, but my guess: you can link against an overload that uses types referenced by your project, but as soon as the compiler/linker has to detect the best match (as there are multiple two-parameter-overloads it has to check all of them), it has to know about all types being used by all possible-fitting overloads. Perhaps read [7.4.2 Overload Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx) from the C# spec.

Comment: @CodeCaster I suspected the same, but then I wondered why this did not make a difference:  `SetProgressState(myState, (IntPtr) myWindowHandle);`.  Should that not have made it clear to the complier which I wanted?

Comment: Also, you might want to double check you have PresentationFramework referenced in your project and you're `#using System.Windows`.  Worst case, check the object browser for `Windows.Window`.

Comment: @RyanWH A reference to `System.Windows` makes no difference either, as it is asking specifically for `System.Windows.Window`.  And just to be clear (as the question is not), I am trying to avoid the additional reference if at all possible.

Comment: @DonBoitnott because the compiler doesn't exist just for the happy-case. :-) It should not just return the first best match, but list them all to detect whether ambiguous matches exist, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN page on Overload Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the compiler will start by selecting the potential candidates

> Each of these contexts defines the set of candidate function members and the list of arguments in its own unique way

then, the best target is selected:

> If the set contains only one function member, then that function member is the best function member.

My understanding here is that the compiler doesn't even consider the 2 arguments methods when you call it with 1 argument.  However, when you use the 2 arguments version, it needs information about the argument types.  In this case, it needs to know what `System.Windows.Window` is to be able to determine which overload you want to call.

### Example

Imagine you have 2 classes in separate Class Libraries

```
class Foo
{

}

class Bar : Foo
{

}
```

and 4 methods in an other library

```
static void Do()
{

}

static void Do(Foo foo)
{

}

static void Do(Bar bar)
{

}

static Foo Get()
{
    return new Bar();
}
```

You reference the Methods Library and the Library Containing `Foo`, but not the library containing `Bar`.

Then, in your application, you obtain an object of type `Foo` from the Methods Library (it could be a `Bar` too, but you don't know).  How is the compiler supposed to resolve an eventual call to `Do()` with arguments?

It can't unless it has the type information for Bar as well.

---

As for your subquestion, it's a result of the above plus the fact that a cast doesn't necessarily force an overload to be chosen.  Let's imagine that `System.Windows.Window` derives from `IntPtr` for a moment.  Casting the argument to `IntPtr` doesn't help the compiler resolve the overload at all (see above example).

Since the type information is not present, the compiler emits an error **because it can't know for sure**.  Honestly, for compilers, that's a feature.

Comment: After playing a bit and reading about overload resolution as CodeCaster suggested, I believe you're spot on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand my comments here for clarity.  Your project isn't able to find System.Windows.Window.  I mispoke in my comment when I said you need to put in:

```
using System.Windows;
```

To the file.

Instead, the project needs to have a reference to System.Windows.  The reference you want is given to you in the error message: PresentationFramework.  You will also need to include PresentationCore(a similar error will pop up telling you to add a reference to PresentationCore).

> The type 'System.Windows.Window' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly '**PresentationFramework**, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'